# ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key on Include Statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, ef-core-2.1

Worked a lot with EF 6.x (via designer) and now started on a new project using EF Core.

I'm getting an error that says value cannot be null, not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong. I've got rid of a lot of fields for brevity as there are hundreds.

All these tables are views via synonyms that connect to a different database. I can get it to work fine, if I do each individual call to a database, but as soon as I do include. I get an error on that line. The error I'm getting is

*ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.FindEntry(TKey key)*

**OnGetAsync**

```
      var equipment = _context.EMEMs.Include(x => x.EMEDs).Where(x => x.KeyID.ToString() == key);
      EMEM = await equipment.Include(x => x.EMCM).ThenInclude(x=>x.EMCDs).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

**EMEM**

```
 public class EMEM
    {
        public byte? EMCo { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Equipment Code")]
        public string Equipment { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public Guid? UniqueAttchID { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public long KeyID { get; set; }
        [NotMapped] public string EquipmentDetails => $"{Equipment.Trim()} - {Description} - {VINNumber}";    
        public virtual IEnumerable<EMWH> EMWHs { get; set; }
        public virtual EMCM EMCM { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<udEMED> EMEDs { get; set; }
    }
```

**EMCM**

```
public class EMCM
    {
    [Key]
    public long KeyID { get; set; }

    public byte? EMCo { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<EMEM> EMEMs { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<udEMCD> EMCDs { get; set; }
}
```

**udEMCD**

```
 public class udEMCD
    {
        [Key]
        public long KeyID { get; set; }
        public byte? Co { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string DocumentCategory { get; set; }
        public int Seq { get; set; }
        public Guid? UniqueAttchID { get; set; }
        public virtual udEMDC EMDC { get; set; }

    public virtual EMCM EMCM { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<HQAT> HQATs { get; set; }

}
```

**Context**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EMEM>().ToTable("EMEM").HasOne(x => x.EMCM).WithMany(x => x.EMEMs).HasForeignKey(x => new { x.EMCo, x.Category }).HasPrincipalKey(x => new { x.EMCo, x.Category });
            modelBuilder.Entity<EMEM>().ToTable("EMEM").HasMany(x => x.EMEDs).WithOne(x => x.EMEM).HasForeignKey(x => new { x.Co, x.Equipment }).HasPrincipalKey(x => new { x.EMCo, x.Equipment });


            modelBuilder.Entity<EMCM>().ToTable("EMCM").HasMany(x => x.EMCDs).WithOne(x => x.EMCM)
                .HasForeignKey(x => new { x.Co, x.Category }).HasPrincipalKey(x => new { x.EMCo, x.Category });


            modelBuilder.Entity<udEMCD>().ToTable("udEMCD").HasOne(x => x.EMDC).WithMany(x => x.EMCDs)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.DocumentCategory).HasPrincipalKey(x => x.Category);
            modelBuilder.Entity<udEMDC>().ToTable("udEMDC").HasMany(x => x.EMEDs).WithOne(x => x.EMDC).HasForeignKey(x => new{ x.DocumentCategory}).HasPrincipalKey(x => new{ x.Category});
            modelBuilder.Entity<udEMED>().ToTable("udEMED");
 modelBuilder.Entity<EMWH>().ToTable("EMWH");
            modelBuilder.Entity<EMWI>().ToTable("EMWI");
            modelBuilder.Entity<HQAT>().HasOne(x => x.EMWH).WithMany(x => x.HQATs).HasForeignKey(x => x.UniqueAttchID)
                .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.UniqueAttchID);
            modelBuilder.Entity<EMWH>().HasOne(x => x.EMEM).WithMany(x => x.EMWHs)
                .HasForeignKey(x => new {x.EMCo, x.Equipment}).HasPrincipalKey(x => new {x.EMCo, x.Equipment});
```

**EDIT:** I added nullable KeyID's just to test prior to uploading and still didn't work.

Comment: `KeyID` should not be nullable. if it is nullable, you can't do `.ToString()` on it.

Also, as a side note, the naming on these models implies ridiculous amount of domain Knowledge. Go work out that relationship between EMCM and EMCD is off a composite key of Co and Category... i wouldn't want to maintain this.. ever

Comment: Becasue of the nullable, you may want to consider `x => x.KeyID != null && x.KeyID.ToString() == key` to avoid null references. Or make it not nullable, as long as it has the `[Key]` attribute

Comment: Sorry, that was something I tested prior to uploading code. Doesn't work with it not nullable as well.

@zaitsman I know it's a terrible naming scheme, and I could change it on my side, but the software that I'm grabbing the information has this as the naming conventions and that's what I need to use when actually working with their database for reporting etc, it's easier for me to keep it consistent so I'm not remembering multiple tables for the same thing..

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is that you're declaring the Key as nullable, which it should never happen.

```
[Key]
public long? KeyID { get; set; }
```

change your code to this...

```
[Key]
public long KeyID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Sorry, that was something I tested prior to uploading code. Doesn't work with it not nullable as well.